# SQL computed column based on OR clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Flights
WHERE Flights.From='Rome' OR Flights.To='London';
```

Is there any way I can add a computed column like `matched` to flag which field was matched?

```
| number | from     | to     | matched |
|--------|----------|--------|---------|
| 1      | Rome     | Munich | "from"  |
| 2      | New York | London | "to"    |
| 3      | Berlin   | London | "to"    |
```

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
       WHEN Flights.From='Rome' THEN 'From'
       WHEN Flights.To='London' THEN 'To'
     END as matched
FROM Flights
WHERE Flights.From='Rome' OR Flights.To='London'
```

You can create a CASE STATEMENT that mimics your logic of your WHERE statement.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
       WHEN Flights.From IN ('Rome','London','etc.')
             AND Flights.To IN ('Rome','London','etc.') THEN Flights.From || ', ' || Flights.To
       WHEN Flights.From IN ('Rome','London','etc.') THEN Flights.From
       WHEN Flights.To IN ('Rome','London','etc.') THEN Flights.To
     END as MatchedValue
     ,CASE
       WHEN Flights.From IN ('Rome','London','etc.')
             AND Flights.To IN ('Rome','London','etc.') THEN 'Both'
       WHEN Flights.From IN ('Rome','London','etc.') THEN 'From'
       WHEN Flights.To IN ('Rome','London','etc.') THEN 'To'
     END as MatchedDirection
FROM Flights
WHERE Flights.From='Rome' OR Flights.To='London'
```

When using case statements the First WHEN condition that is met will be the answer so if BOTH of your conditions are met and you want to see that the first WHEN condition has to look for that possibility.

Comment: Thanks. Can I also get the matched value? Here `Rome` or `London`? I'm asking for queries that use `IN` operator. I need to fill the computed column with matched value.

Comment: I updated answer with additional example for you based on your comment

Comment: Awesome. Thank you sir.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *, (1087 - Flights.Price) as 'mycolumn'
FROM Flights
WHERE Flights.From='Rome' OR Flights.To='London';
```